# Data Analysis: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

Im cleaning some data and encountered the TypeError and I haven't been able to figure out exactly what is wrong with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
# use loop to merge date and time into DateTime (w/progress bar)
def create_datetime_axis(daf):
    datetime_axis = []
    for row_n in tqdm(range(len(daf))):
        srs = daf.iloc[row_n, :]
        datetime_axis.append(datetime.strptime(''.join((srs['DATE'], srs['TIME'])), '%m/%d/%Y%H:%M').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
    return datetime_axis
In [61]:
```

```
# drop the TIME column and replace the DATE column with the new and improved DATETIME
filtered_df = df.copy()
filtered_df['DATE'] = create_datetime_axis(filtered_df)
filtered_df.drop('TIME', axis=1, inplace=True)
filtered_df.rename(columns={'DATE':'DATETIME'}, inplace=True)
filtered_df
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-f651516bbd66> in <module>
      1 # drop the TIME column and replace the DATE column with the new and improved DATETIME
      2 filtered_df = df.copy()
----> 3 filtered_df['DATE'] = create_datetime_axis(filtered_df)
      4 filtered_df.drop('TIME', axis=1, inplace=True)
      5 filtered_df.rename(columns={'DATE':'DATETIME'}, inplace=True)

<ipython-input-60-0e8f272e1aee> in create_datetime_axis(daf)
      2 def create_datetime_axis(daf):
      3     datetime_axis = []
----> 4     for row_n in tqdm(range(len(daf))):
      5         srs = daf.iloc[row_n, :]
      6         datetime_axis.append(datetime.strptime(''.join((srs['DATE'], srs['TIME'])), '%m/%d/%Y%H:%M').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Show us your imports.

Comment: What is `tqdm` bound to? And `range` and `len`?

Comment: Because the expression `tqdm(range(len(daf))` makes 3 calls, any of those three names could be the problem here; you could have assigned a module to `range` or `len` by accident, or used `import tqdm` and so should use `tqdm.tqdm(range(len(df))` or change your import to `from tqdm import tqdm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change it to:

```
# use loop to merge date and time into DateTime (w/progress bar)
def create_datetime_axis(daf):
    datetime_axis = []
    for row_n in tqdm.tqdm(range(len(daf))):
        srs = daf.iloc[row_n, :]
        datetime_axis.append(datetime.strptime(''.join((srs['DATE'], srs['TIME'])), '%m/%d/%Y%H:%M').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
    return datetime_axis
```

or change your `import tqdm` to `from tqdm import tqdm`

Comment: Thank you, This worked!